# Set webconfig key httpmaxcollection value dynamically on pageload or form submision

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Dynamically generated webform, I would like to set webconfig key httpmaxcollection value dynamically on page rendering or form submission , is there any way to do this dynamically ??
what all are issues(if any) that may affect my site if i set the value to a huge one like 100000

Comment: i need to set it on any of the following
Pageload
Function call
Form submission

Comment: i need to set it on any of the following

Comment: changing the web-config will restart the application..so basically you will be restarting the application every time you change the web-config dynamically which is not recommended and I believe is of no use..Instead of it..try using some state management techniques

Comment: If you need to post more than 1000 fields in your generated webform then you probably need to re-think your design. Maye split up the form in two or more parts and send each part by themselves?

Comment: Thank you , i also would like to redesign this stuff but its a different scenario , its an existing application running for past few years and form is generated dynamically , which i mentioned , so due to this reasons re designing alone cant fix it , and each time when users create more and more fields in the form iam forced to modify the webconfig and upload it again, so will this issue be solved by setting a huge value like 100000 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this application targeting ASP.NET 4.x?  If so, install .NET 4.5 on the web server.  The default "max collection count" value was bumped to Int32.MaxValue in .NET 4.5.

Note: .NET 4.5 is an in-place upgrade to .NET 4.0, so as long as your application targets 4.x you'll get the new behavior automatically.